# awk - search for multiple strings in file and store specific word from this line to print all of them on one line at the end

Tags: awk

I'm new on this forum and just started with awk and I like to do the following.

Input file (input.log) :

```
first word of file
second line in file
third and last line
```

awk script (test.awk) I have so far, finding strings and storing them to print at the end on one line  :

```
/first/ ( aaa = $2 )
/in/ ( bbb = $1 )
/last/ ( ccc = $3 )
{ print aaa " , " bbb " , " ccc }

awk -f test.awk input.log
```

Actual Output:

```
first word of file
first word of file
first word of file
word , first , of
second line in file
second line in file
second line in file
line , second , in
third and last line
third and last line
third and last line
and , third , last
```

Expected (wanted) output:

```
word , second , last
```

Any help and advice would be much appriciated.

Br. Bert

Comment: Your script appears to be using round brackets `()` where curly brackets are needed.  You say you want to print the results at the end, but you have no `END` block.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean this, with `{}` instead of `()`:

```
/ first / { aaa = $2 }
/ in / { bbb = $1 }
/ last / { ccc = $3 }
END { print aaa " , " bbb " , " ccc }
```

If you omit the spaces around your *regex* `/in/`, your script will match the line containing the word `in` but also the word `line` present in other lines.

The last statement must be preceded by `END` and will only be executed once, when the whole file is processed.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler just said the same as I did in his comment above, but he didn't see the problem of the missing spaces around the *regex*.

Comment: More accurately, I didn't comment on it :D. I'm puzzled by the number of repeated lines in the output.  There are 3 repeats of the first line, but I was under the illusion that each of four patterns (`/first/`, `( aaa = $2 )`, `( bbb = $1 )` and `( ccc = $3 )`) would trigger an implicit `print $0` operation. _[…time passeth; enlightenment striketh…]_ Except, maybe, that the existing `{ print … }` is associated with `( ccc = $3 )`.  That doesn't quite account for it, I think, unless the line spacing in the script in the question is different from the line spacing actually used.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and explaining why!!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler every line of the script has a true condition because they say, for example `/first/ ( aaa = $2 )` which is the string concatenation of the result of `$0 ~ /first/` which is either 0 or 1 which  the result of `aaa=$2` which is whatever string is in $2, so the result is a string like `1word` or `0line` which no matter what is always a non-null string which  is then treated as a true condition to cause a default print  of the current line. The assignment to the variables always happens so the script exactly as posted would be expected to produce the output shown in the question.

Comment: @EdMorton — thanks.  It hadn't occurred to.me that you could do strong concatenation between terms in the pattern part of a `pattern action` line.  It's not something I've ever had a need for and I'm not sure there are many circumstances where it is useful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler right, it's almost always a bug and even when it's not it should be written more clearly as `(x y) != ""{foo}` at least instead of just `x y{foo}`, especially if `x` or `y` is actually the result of a regexp comparison as in this case!